# How to enable cache in dev mode?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig, symfony4

I'm working on a heavy-load Symfony optimization, trying out template cache, doctrine cache, etc. But unless I'm wrong, those caches are disabled in dev, so it's hard to evaluate the effect of those optimizations.

Is there a way to enable caching in dev mode, so I can the application optimization results while keeping the debug bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there are couple of assumptions in your question that are not true:

- By default, Twig is **always** cached. Check the docs [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html#cache). You can only *disable* caching, if for some reason you need to disable it during development. But more likely than not, it's not going to be great for you.
- There is **no *default* Doctrine caching enabled on production**. If you want to enable caching, you'd need to do it yourself (by creating the appropriate file in `config/packages/prod/doctrine.yml`, but you'd first need to verify exactly what type of caching you'd need and how to configure it. Check some docs about doctrine caching [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/caching.html).

---

In the end, changing settings on `dev` (or any environment) it's just a matter of creating the another file with the appropriate settings within `config/packages/[environment_name]`.

You should already have a few inside `config/packages/dev/`.

To create specific settings for an environment just add a couple of files to adjust   these settings.

E.g. you could have a `config/packages/dev/doctrine.yml` with this inside (a basic doctrine caching configuration):

```
services:
    doctrine.result_cache_provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.result_cache_pool'
    doctrine.system_cache_provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.system_cache_pool'

framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.app
            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.system
```

Comment: Thanks, checking it out. Right now i'm trying to get the test environment to get but it won't show the debug toolbar even tough the bundle is loaded and configuration file is present (by default).

Comment: The `test` environment is meant to run unit tests. You are fine using `dev`. No need to change to a different environment. Mostly, you already have the settings you need there. (Twig is cached, container generated is cached, doctrine is not unless you want to cache it).

Comment: Well, i've been playing around with the controller cache annotation, doctrine query useResultCache method and can't see any visible performance change, in dev mode or on a stress test in production. But the book i'm using is about Symfony 3.4, it's probably outdated on many points.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the configuration for each of these parts? For example, in older Symfony versions, there could be a file somewhere (depending on the Symfony version you've started the project with, it could for example reside at `config/packages/dev/twig.yaml`) that defines the Twig cache as following:

```
twig:
    cache: false
```

By setting this to a valid caching directory, you can enable the cache, regardless of the environment running your application.

In other packages, there might be similar settings. Have a look for overriden settings, either in `config/packages/dev` and `config/packages/prod` for more recent versions or files like `config/services_prod.yaml` and `config/services_dev.yaml` for a bit older versions. But without knowing which packages you use, it's hard to provide a general answer.

Comment: Sorry Nico, but this is wrong `true` is not a valid setting for `twig.cache`. And cache is already enabled by default unless you deliberately disable it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, Yivi. That was meant to be an example about where to look for such configuration. I'll adjust my answer